# MLA formatting of book series

Tags: mla

I'm not sure if this is the right area for this question but here we go. I'm in the middle of an essay (for a college English class) and I reference several book series by name. I know the individual books would be italicized but how are series' names formatted? I've done a quick google search and there appear to be conflicting responses.
Two book series that I reference are the Lord of the Rings and Harry Potter. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about manuscript formatting style, and not English language and usage.

Comment: It would help if you actually stated your research and gave us the 'responses' which you mention. Welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question, the **book series is formatted with the title case** (capitalizing the first letter of each word). The MLA format for citing a book part of a series is as follows:

(Author Surname), (Author First Name). *(Book name in Italics, no title case)*. (Series Name In Title Case). (City of publication): (Name of the publishing company), (Year of publishing). Print.

For example:

> Tolkien, John R. R.. *The Fellowship of the Ring*. The Lord Of The
>   Rings Trilogy. New York: George Allen & Unwin, 1954. Print.

*Note: the publication year has to be specific for the particular book from the series. You can find the publication information in the first few pages of the book.*

Comment: It is usual to supply a link to your citation. I know links may not be permanent but initially they are useful for clarification.